# Do you have to have a default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop

Say I have a class. I want it to have a constructor that takes certain arguments, so I make one. Do I still need to have a constructor that has no arguments (default constructor) even if I don't need it? In other words, do i *have* to include `Class()` as a member function even if I don't need it?

Comment: No, you don't *have* to. What makes you ask this?

Comment: I think it is up to what you need

Comment: if it is never called, there is no need for it. But it may be indirectly referenced(will pop compiler error) if you fail to initialize your class in another class' initializer list

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Yes, you need to have a default constructor. The program won't compile otherwise.

Comment: This answer is so wrong that three users voted to delete it, but you still want to re-post it?

Answer (score 9):

No, if you don't need it then you don't need it.

You only need it if you want to be able to default-initialise the class. Often you don't want that - you only want objects to exist if they were correctly initialised with the constructor(s) you wrote - which is why declaring your own constructor removes the implicit default constructor.

Comment: You also need it if you want to value-initialize the class.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed; although that's the same thing once you've declared a constructor.

Answer (score 8):

No. Make a class that does what you need, not one that adheres to cargo cults for no reason. Rubber duck the class if in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors decide how you can instantiate your class. SO, it's upto you to design constructors. Sometimes you want user of that class to create object only by specifying values for data members (rather than having some default value ) by excluding default constructor for that class.

Answer (score 1):

No not really unless you use certain third party libraries which expect you to have default constructor.

Comment: And then you need to think really carefully about your use of those libraries, because constructing your object into an invalid state violates RAII. Sometimes.

Comment: It does but you cant really guarantee that in some cases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I like to define a "null state" in these cases, usually via `bool m_null;`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Knew it ;) But sometimes you have to deal with libraries which except a default ctor to be present, e.g. in Qt the containers. Each of your custom types however tend to implement "optionality", each on its own, which I guess is what you don't like.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *expect... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a C-like array or a std::array of that type, it has to have a default constructor, because when you allocate memory for the array, at compile time, it needs to call the default constructor to create the instances.

```
class Bird {
public:
  Bird(int a) {} // adding this line removes compiler generated default constr.
  void fly() {}
};

int main() {
  unordered_set<Bird> birds; // ok, does not do instantiation of Bird
  Bird birdsArr[100]; // compile error - cannot create Bird - no default constr.
  std::array<Bird, 100> birdies; // same error as raw array
}
```